# Collapse pandas dataframe columns by an input value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have product this kind of excel file.

[excel file before input value]

[image: 2]

Now I want to insert an input date time value and obtain a new excel format where all the columns with the date YYYY/MM are <= of my input value, collapse into one column and all the value sum each other per each rows.

If for example I insert 2020/04 as input I will obtain something like that:

[excel file after input value]

[image: 1]

I don't know how to do that, pls thank you all

Comment: Please post your data as plain text (no image). And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can just select your columns and run `.sum()` on them.

```py
sum_cols = ['Will Expire on 2019/05', 'Will Expire on 2020/05', 'Will Expire on 2020/03']
df['expired_@_etc_date'] = df[sum_cols ].sum(axis=1)
display(df)
```